# Weird results reading index 0 from the stack

Tags: c++, lua

Normally the Lua stack begins at index 1. However, I noticed a strange phenomenon when reading the stack address 0 provided by calling a cfunction.

```
--lua tables defined via Lua C API
h{ }
u{ }
f{ u{ s{} } }
--table calls
h(2)
u(3)
f.u.s(4)
```

All the above seen tables (`h`, `u`, and the nested `s`) have a  `__call` metamethod pointing to the same cfunction. From that cfunction I'm reading/dumping the passed stack:

```
while(start_index <= lua_gettop(state)) {
    switch(lua_type(state, start_index)) {
        case LUA_TNUMBER:
            std::cout << "LUA_TNUMBER:"<<lua_tonumber(state, start_index);
            break;
        //... dump for all the other types
```

When `start_index` starts at 1, the output is as expected: `LUA_TABLE LUA_TNUMBER:3`; It contains the table that contains the metamethod (or so I think) and the argument, `3`.

---

However when `start_index` starts at 0, I'd imagine the result is not a valid Lua type, but it is. The results are inconsistent: When calling from Lua, index `0` is always a `LUA_TNUMBER` with the value `5`.

When however calling from C++ with pcall (`lua_getfield, lua_pushnumber, lua_pcall`), index 0 yields the same `LUA_TNUMBER(5)` for calling `f.u.s`, but `LUA_TABLE` for `h` and `u`.

**What is at index 0, why is it a valid Lua type, and why is its value so weirdly inconsistent?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0 is not a valid stack index, so you can't rely on finding anything there. It's kinda like taking your `lua_State` pointer and dereferencing `(lua_State - 1)` and asking what the value there is. It's garbage.

From the [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.1):

> Any function in the API that receives stack indices works only with *valid indices* or *acceptable indices*.
>
> A *valid index* is an index that refers to a real position within the stack, that is, its position lies between 1 and the stack top (1 = abs(index) = top).
>
> An *acceptable index* can be any *valid index*, including the pseudo-indices, but it also can be any positive index after the stack top within the space allocated for the stack, that is, indices up to the stack size.
>
> **(Note that 0 is never an acceptable index)**

Looking at the source (see [index2addr](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lapi.c.html)), it looks like if Lua is built with `LUA_USE_APICHECK`, your call would thrown an error.